# External mini SAS to external mini SAS (x4 vs x8)?

Tags: raid, hard-drive, sas

I'm ordering an Enhance Tec E8 external harddrive enclosure with with a Mini SAS 8088 connector. I plan to use 8 drives in a RAID 5. The RAID Controller I'm looking at says it has 2 x4/x8 hybrid ports, however all the ext mini SAS to mini SAS cables I can find say x4.
Does that mean the x4 can only address 4 harddrives and I'd need to get two x4 cables to take use of all 8 harddrives or am I misunderstanding something here?

Thanks!

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked up that unit, and I suspect you are talking about the E8-MS unit.  That unit has two Mini-SAS ports on it, which you would use SFF-8088 cables to connect from the controller to the box.  Those cables are designed to support 4 drives each, not by arbitrary decision, but by the physical wiring of the cables.  If the controller says it supports x8 ports, then it must be referring to a special cable they make/sell to connect to 8 drives.  However, you will still need 2 SFF-8088 cables to connect to the E8-MS unit.

Comment: Just to illustrate this a bit, there's a few good diagrams here:
http://www.enhance-tech.com/products/desktop/E8_MS.html